# php error:Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Okay I know this question has been asked multiple times but sadly, I was still unable to fix the problem.

When trying to run this simple script:

```
<?php

   mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

?>
```

I get the error mentioned in the title.
Info: 
-I am using XAMPP 
-There is a folder named mysql in my XAMPP folder 
-I put this line on my php.ini: extension=php_mysql.dll
and there already was: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll 
-I am using Widnows. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The `mysql` API is gone as of PHP 7.

Comment: 7.0.3   What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) ("improved") or [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thank you very very much :D

Comment: to elaborate a little: The extension providing the mysql_* functions has been removed from php7. see http://docs.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using php7, mysql_* functions are removed as they are deprecated use mysqli_* instead.

Here is a link you can use 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php